# Oracle PL/SQL - best way to do select, group-by, order-by, where-clause on different columns, based on a condition?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Hi I have a problem which requires me to do a select on different columns, based on a condition. I can achieve this in a stored proc with an unclean IF ELSIF clause but I would like to know the best way to solve this. Here's an example to make it clearer:

```
PROCEDURE notSoSmartSelect(type IN VARCHAR, a_filter IN VARCHAR
             , b_filter IN VARCHAR, results OUT SYS_REFCURSER) IS
BEGIN
  IF type = 'A' THEN
    OPEN results FOR 
      SELECT a, sum(val) v FROM sample_table
      GROUP BY a, ORDER BY a;
  ELSIF type = 'B' THEN
    OPEN results FOR 
      SELECT b, a, sum(val) v FROM sample_table
      WHERE a = a_filter
      GROUP BY b, a, ORDER BY a, b;
  ELSIF type = 'C' THEN
    OPEN results FOR 
      SELECT c, b, a, sum(val) v FROM sample_table
      WHERE a = a_filter AND b = b_filter
      GROUP BY c, b, a, ORDER BY a, b, c;
  END IF;
END;
```

As you have noticed, in each case, the table used is the same but there are different columns being used to fetch, filter, group and order.

The above code looks quite simple but the actual problem has many branches and has multiple if-else, which makes the code very dirty. Is there an elegant and clean way to approach this? Maybe Dynamic SQL? But I cant seem to figure out the best way to write dynamic sql for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider this "unclean". The queries are very different from each other, so I wouldn't try to merge them into a single statement.

But given that they are so different (different columns selected, different aggregation groups, different where clauses), why are they all in one procedure? I'd make this three procedures if any; probably rather three views.

Answer (score 0):

This is much clearer than the dynamic sql approach you would like to try. As mentioned you have many IF ELSE branches it would become very tedious to even construct that many and `"TEST"` that many conditions.

In my opinion your `refcursor` is used by any front end application like `JAVA` so its better to RETURN the whole output and then do all the manipulations from that end.

Comment: I would prefer doing it that way but unfortunately there are about half a million records... and it takes too long to fetch so many at a time from the database, while the queries with the where clause only return about 60 records.

Comment: Then unfortunately this is the only approach I could think off